# IconicTileData BackgroundColor not being displayed

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to use the IconicTileData class in Windows Phone 8, all is working well except for the colour of the tile.

No matter what I set the property to the tile displays the accent colour and not the provided one.

```
ShellTile.Create(navigateUri, new IconicTileData
{
    Title = category.Name,
    BackgroundColor = Colors.Magenta,
    IconImage = new Uri("/Resources/Tiles/IconicLarge.png", UriKind.Relative),
    SmallIconImage= new Uri("/Resources/Tiles/IconicSmall.png", UriKind.Relative)
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure why this works but adding a

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Yield();
```

before the call to ShellTile.Create appears to work.